# why pygraphivz layout() move the nodes which have attr 'pin=true'?

Tags: graphviz, pygraphviz

my code :

```
A.layout('neato', args='-Gsep=+250 -Gsplines=ortho -Goverlap=false')
A.draw('1.svg')

#do something, add new nodes with pos to A,
add_some_nodes_to_A()

for node in A.nodes():
    node.attr['pos'] += '!'
    node.attr['pin'] = 'true'
A.layout('neato', args='-Gsep=+250 -Gsplines=ortho -Goverlap=false - Gnotranslate=true')
A.draw('2.svg')
```

before the second layout, all A's nodes have pined, why the nodes move in 2.svg?

Comment: add 1.svg(left) and 2.svg(right) image: http://p1.bpimg.com/1949/62ff3275704f045e.png